# IntelliJ IDEA: Webjars / Maven / Spring MVC - How to correctly import dependencies and have them work?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, glassfish

So I'm beginning Java Web development and I'd just like to have some libraries imported to my IntelliJ project correctly through use of Maven. I've stumbled upon making use of Webjars in order to import bootstrap and jquery, but I am having a great deal of trouble getting anything to work correctly. Wondering if someone could help out? Any suggestions are appreciated.

My project currently has Maven and Spring MVC as supported frameworks. My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaEEHelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

</beans>
```

My index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Awesome site.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/webjars/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

If I try adding the following line to my spring-config.xml, I get this error:
[image: Cannot resolve]

More screenshots:

My project explorer which for some reason never created subdirectories for bootstrap or jquery:
[image: Project explorer]

The errors I'm seeing at runtime:
[image: Runtime errors]

Comment: You should have `<mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" mapping="/webjars/**"/>`.

Comment: @manish he/she is using Java 8 and Glassfish 4.1.0, so I'm sure the `web.xml` is Servlet 3.0 compatible...having this: `<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/" />` is enough

Comment: @manish - I get the same error with that location path. It doesn't understand what "classpath:" is.

Comment: Ignore the errors you see in the IDE for the time being.  Have the runtime errors been resolved?  Lets fix one issue at a time.

Comment: @manish - so I used your line of code in my spring-config.xml and it successfully deployed but I am getting 404 errors at runtime when it tries to load the resources from HTML.

Example:
`http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Did the others work or are all of them still failing?  Also, it will be better if you use `RELEASE` versions instead of `LATEST` versions, which could include snapshots.

Comment: All responded with 404 errors.

Okay - I switched to `RELEASE` in my dependencies and redeployed successfully and refreshed the web page. Now the exceptions aren't as verbose and one reports a 404, where the others just say that an error occurred.

Comment: `GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css 
localhost/:7 GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js 
localhost/:8 GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Weird, when I refresh the page I get incorrect errors like those immediately above, but when I navigate to the page in a new tab, then I get 404 errors for every resource I attempt to load.

Comment: And, I am assuming your context root is `/` (otherwise, that should precede `/webjars`).  Is it possible for you to upload a sample project somewhere (say, Github)?  All of this is certainly unexpected.

Comment: @manish - sure, I just pushed it to github. Thanks for your help, by the way. https://github.com/NateFuller/Beginning-Java-Web-Dev. Is what is currently pushed enough for you to start the project and attempt to replicate? I used a .gitignore so I'm not sure if you require any additional metadata files.

Comment: Ok, I should have paid more attention earlier. Your Maven project structure is incorrect. I have corrected the project structure and submitted a pull request on your project. If you merge the pull request, take the latest code, run `mvn clean tomcat7:run` and hit `http://localhost:8080/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css`, you should be all set. I have added Tomcat 7 Maven plugin to the project so that you can test everything without using an external server. Once you are happy, run `mvn clean package` to generate a WAR file that you can deploy on an external server (say, Glassfish).