# IntelliJ and Spring MVC, cannot resolve location /webjars/

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, location, webjars

I've got a problem with intelliJ and Spring mvc. IntelliJ can't resolve location /webjars/ when I add to `spring-config.xml` (in my project its called `todo-servlet.xml`). I try to use bootstrap and jQuery.

The mapping I use:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
```

I also tried

```
<mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" mapping="/webjars/**"/>
```

but that didn't work either... IntelliJ doesn't see location.

Here's link to that project on GitHub: [My GitHub Project ToDoList](https://github.com/PiotrBartoch/ToDoList)

That's probably the same issue as here : [IntelliJ IDEA: Webjars / Maven / Spring MVC - How to correctly import dependencies and have them work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663149/intellij-idea-webjars-maven-spring-mvc-how-to-correctly-import-dependenci)

It's solved but none left a solution..

Comment: do you use maven?

Comment: Yes. Dependencies i loaded with maven are: bootstrap 3.3.6 and jquerry 1.9.1 from org.webjars ofc

Comment: I faced with the same issue. Despite of Idea swears on the mapping: location="/webjars/" it works okay in runtime. It seems that Intellij Idea isn't so advanced and can't resolve such kind of dependency placed in local maven repo.